# User input in capistrano 3.4

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

According to the documentation of capistrano, I can get user input with the ask() method. I created the following task:

```
desc "Ask for user input"
task :ask_for_user_input do
  ask ':update_assets', 'Update assets (y/n, default=n)?', 'n'
end
```

and in deploy.rb I have

```
namespace :deploy do
  ...
  before :deploy, "deploy:ask_for_user_input"
  ...
end
```

But no matter what, capistrano never asks for user input. I tried different variations (e.g. putting the "ask" method directly in deploy.rb or my stage files but it did not change anything. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prompt for user input in my staging file. Perhaps it's your syntax? The `ask()` method can be used like this:

```ruby
# ask for user input
ask(:update_assets, 'Update assets (y/n, default=n)', 'n', echo: true)
# get the user input
fetch(:update_assets)
```

Sources: [Capistrano User Input](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/user-input/#), [How can I get Capistrano to prompt for a password?](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/how-can-i-get-capistrano-to-prompt-for-a-password/#)

Comment: Well thanks a lot, without the "fetch" it did not work.

Comment: To add why the code isn't working without the "fetch", from the Capistrano User Input's page: _Important! ask will not prompt the user immediately. The question is deferred until the first time fetch is used to obtain the setting._